# opencv error link error in compresive tracking

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CompressiveTracker::processFrame(class cv::Mat &,class cv::Rect_ &)" (?processFrame@CompressiveTracker@@QAEXAAVMat@cv@@AAV?$Rect_@H@3@@Z) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\anc6kor\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CT\CT\CT.obj CT

Comment: you forgot to add CompressiveTracker.cpp to your proj ?

Comment: Thank u.. its running now..